# facebook website app not publishing read activity on timeline for all users

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have created a facebook website open graph application for my website www.heyngine.com. The read action has been submitted and approved by facebook. When I use it from my personal facebook account or my website facebook account it works just fine. When I tried to use it from 2-3 other facebook accounts activities are not published on my timeline and cannot been viewed under activity logs.

Please note that my personal fb account is not linked to any application Role (Administrators, Developers etc.).

this is a link leading to my application(website):
http://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?app_id=330267687026774&method=permissions.request&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.heyngine.com%2Findex.php%3Foption%3Dcom_content%26view%3Darticle%26id%3D1761099%253A---2---%26catid%3D133%253Awwwethnosgr%26Itemid%3D499%26fb_action_ids%3D382549068460477%26fb_action_types%3Dnews.reads%26fb_source%3Daggregation%26fb_aggregation_id%3D288381481237582&response_type=token&display=page&auth_referral=1

Please advice
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not asking the [publish_actions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/#extended_perms) extended permission. You need this permission to post actions on timeline or super-set [publish_stream](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/#extended_perms)

That is why its not posting on timeline. You can check the error message in firebug->net tab

> /**/ FB._callbacks.__gcb2({"error":{"message":"(#200) Requires
>   extended permission:
>   publish_actions","type":"OAuthException","code":200}});

Timeline screenshot
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I had added publish_actions in 'User & Friend Permissions' and publish_stream in Extended Permissions but nothing has been changed yet. Maybe it requires some time for the change to be applied on fb servers. On the other hand I noticed the following message under my published actions: 
'Read This Article (insecure)'
'In order for this action to be displayed to non-developers, this must be a secure url'
any ideas on that? does my website need to be ssl certified in order to be compatible with fb og?

Comment: Its working for me here. You should check the permission given by an user to app when user comes to your site. if user has revoked permission, then you should again ask him to grant access. Re https, there was no mention in the doc that website requires https. But if it an facebook app(canvas, tab) then it requires https (as many users enabled https for their a/c). For non https users, it still works.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. You have been very helpful. Have a nice day.